# How to Specify CornerRadius for custom TextBox control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, textbox, styles

I have created custom ctextbox with the following code. But I am not able provide the roundcorner border for this.

```
public class FilteredTextBox : TextBox
{


    public FilteredTextBox()
        : base()
    {
        IsNumeric = false;
        IsRegex = false;
        IsRequired = false;
        ErrorMsg = "";
        RegexText = "";
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        Margin = new Thickness(0);
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        var border = new Border {CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(4)};
     }
   }
```

Please guide me on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a style for your custom `TextBox`:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="CustomTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
              <Border
                CornerRadius="4"
                Padding="2"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1" >
                <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      <CustomTextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxStyle}" Text="TextBox with CornerRadius" BorderBrush="Black" />
    </Grid>

  </Grid>
</Page>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this as a tack-on to punker76's great response:

If you ever want to modify any of the default styles for the current `FrameworkElement` objects available in .Net there are a number of ways to approach it, but I always like this handy tool:

[Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2091)